# Imagemagick splitting image by black lines

Tags: python, image, imagemagick

I have image which is divided by black lines.
Is is possible to split image into multiple  parts  divided by  black lines using Imagemagick
(Python or any other solution)
Could not fine any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the `sum` for each row.
If the Row is all black (sum=0) extract this part into a new image and you are done.

Comment: Thanks. Do think that this will help I have multiple small areas(grid with curve lines )

Comment: If the lines are curves this will not work. Can you post a sample picture?